# ExpressionEngine Conditionals if:elseif

Tags: conditionals

I'm having trouble getting a condition to evaluate properly: http://goo.gl/wWkw4E.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. If an image has been uploaded, show image 1
2. If no image has been uploaded but the post is category 4, show image 2 (male)
3. If no image has been uploaded and the post is not category 4, show image 3 (female)

Your help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Why are using a contain operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the point of using an manipulation on conditional. All manipulations are generated for the directory you set to use on the field.

Please, test this:

```
{categories}
  {if voice_talent_headshot}
    {voice_talent_headshot:thumb80}
  {if:elseif category_id == '4'}
    {assets}/images/headshot-man.png
  {if:else}
    {assets}/images/headshot-woman.png
  {/if}
{/categories}
```